# array of variables with common properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, properties, case

I have created a sort of slider that is based on a variable called workChart containing values from 1 to 15 (could be more). Now these elements (works) are divided in 3 categories also.
I defined also global lists that contain the names of the works from each category as:

```
gtitlesCol = [12,7,6,3,2,1];
gtitlesRech = [13,5,4];
gtitlesCorp = [15,14];
```

Now I would love that each value(work) all over the site will be recorded to make part of its category so that I am able to avoid things like these:

```
switch( workChart ) {
    case 3:  switchCategory( "Recherche");   break;
    case 5:  switchCategory( "Collection" ); break;
    case 12: switchCategory( "Recherche");   break;
    case 13: switchCategory( "Corporate" );
};
```

Is there a clever way to „nest“ the category into the workChart value? So that I may use the variable workChart and it would no longer be necessary to tell a function each time to which category it belongs. I presume it has to do with creating them as objects (works) with properties (category f.e.) but I don’t know how to handle it. Any help there? Thanks a lot!

@Tobias

I am sorry Tobias, I guess my question was even more simple than you could imagine and my poor explanations made you waste your time. Sorry for that. I succeeded to do what I want with:

```
var categories = { 1:"Collection", 2:"Collection", 3:"Collection", 4:"Recherche", 5:"Recherche", 6:"Collection", 7:"Collection", 8:"Collection", 9:"Collection", 10:"Collection", 11:"Collection", 12:"Collection", 13:"Recherche", 14:"Corporate", 14:"Corporate" }
```

Then I can do (f.e.)

```
alert( categories[5] );
```

or do something else with it. Now the only thing that lacks, I guess, is a more agreeable syntax form for my array in order not to repeat 15 times instead of, I guess, 3 times.

Comment: First of all, what language are you working with?

Comment: In the future, you should tag the language. 1) for better exposure and 2) So users know what language you are working with

Comment: Have you considered using a some kind of map? I'm not familiar with javascript, but I know you can use some kind of map like you can in Java.

Comment: I am starting to read about that. Thanks. I also may add here that I have already jquery in my code so maybe there is a simple solution using it and I am also more familiar with it than with pure JS.

Comment: Well, you misunderstand one thing: this is exactly the same what I did, just instead of having multiple objects of one type you have one object with numbers as variable names and category strings as values. What you have created is not an array, the fact that you can access it using array notation [] stems from the fact that this is how JavaScript works, you can access variables using array-notation or dot notation. In this case dot notation will not work because the variable name is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you presume correctly, you can create WorkChart as an object. Below you will find an example implementation assuming you may want to do something (process in any way) with this category and value and then have it ready to return:

```
function WorkChart(cat,objVal) {
    var category = cat,
        retValue = objVal,

        getCategory = function() {
            // any code handling category
            return category;
        },

        retValue = function() {
            // any code handling value
            return retValue;
        };

        return {
            category: getCategory,
            value: retValue
        }
};


var wrkCh1 = new WorkChart("Recherche",13);
var category = wrkCh1.category();
var value = wrkCh1.value();
```

This is a simple object just for returning data. If you want to have an opportunity to change object values after creation you can change the above to setters/getters version like:

```
function WorkChart(cat,objVal) {
    var category = cat,
        retValue = objVal,

        getCategory = function() {
            return category;
        },

        getValue = function() {
            return retValue;
        },

        changeCategory = function(newCat) {
            // any code handling category
            category = newCat;
        },

        changeValue = function(newVal) {
            // any code handling value
            retValue = newVal;
        };

        return {
            category: getCategory,
            value: getValue,
            setCategory: changeCategory,
            setValue: changeValue
        }
};

var workCh1 = new WorkChart("Recherche",13);
var category = workCh1.category();
var value = workCh1.value();

workCh1.setCategory("Corporate");
workCh1.setValue(15);

category = workCh1.category();
value = workCh1.value();
```

Regarding to your comment there are many ways to create an array of objects and then pass on one of those to function, e.g.

```
var workCharts = new Array();
workCharts.push(new WorkChart("category1",1));
workCharts.push(new WorkChart("category1",3));
workCharts.push(new WorkChart("category1",5));
workCharts.push(new WorkChart("category2",2));
workCharts.push(new WorkChart("category2",4));

//... and so on until you add them all
// now let's take any element
var workChart = workCharts[1];

doSomethingWithWorkChart( workChart);
doSomethingWithWorkChartCategory (workChart);
```

OK, after seeing your edit I can tell you that you can achieve this with one switch function and leave your 3 arrays gtitlesCol,gtitlesRech,gtitlesCorp as they are.

```
function switchCatgegoryByNumber (workChart) {
    if(gtitlesCol.indexOf(workChart != -1) {
       switchCategory( "Collection" );
    }
    else if (gtitlesRech.indexOf(workChart != -1) {
       switchCategory( "Recherche" );
    }
    else if (gtitlesCorp.indexOf(workChart != -1) {
       switchCategory( "Corporate" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Way ahead of my knowledge, but I think the first part is enough. I am looking for a simple way to attach the categories to the values of workChart. So that when have in any function a thing like `doSomethingWithWorkChart( workChart);` I could simply add `doAlsoSomethingWithItsCategory( workChart);` Hope I explain myself

Comment: Something like: ´var workCharts = [ 1,3,5:category1 , 2,4,6,10:category2 , 7,8,9:category3 ]´ Only to explain my concept